# visualising drag and drop in windows forms

Tags: winforms

I have some panels in windows forms, which are placed in flowLayoutPanel. I can perform drag and drop operation with them. Now I want to animate that dragging process, means when dragging one control, during that drag it will be visible on the screen, like it is in windows.
Thanks
ROmo

Comment: Implement the GiveFeedback event.  Set e.UseDefaultCursors to false and assign Cursor.Current to whatever kind of cursor you like.  An example that drags text [is here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/36028246-7fc8-4cda-a582-de8a675a0827/drag-text-as-image?forum=winforms).

Comment: Thank you :) Can I show that control when dragging not just another cursor ?

Comment: Maybe.  It doesn't usually end that well since a control is clipped by its parent.

Comment: But how can I cast Cursor to some control, which is panel Hans ?

Comment: You can't of course.  It only has to *look* like a control while you are dragging.  DrawToBitmap() is an easy way to get a bitmap that looks like it.  You are asking the wrong questions about this, keep this on the shelf until you've gained some experience.  The standard D+D will work well enough until you do.

Comment: Ok,Thanks :) ) What means D+D ?